# XML/XSLT - Change Static Label to Dynamic Label

Tags: xml, xslt, content-management-system

I'm using the XML generated by our CMS to render HTML content on a page with XSLT.

Basically, I need to make a change to the line of code below so that "Areas of Inquiry" is no longer hard-coded to the page, and replace it with whatever link name the user types into the CMS.

```
<a href="{Page[@Name='AreasofInquiryLink']/@URL}">
  <strong>Areas of Inquiry Courses</strong>
</a>:&#160;
```

Here is the XML generated by the CMS:

```
<TaxonomyNavigation 
    StartNodes="2299|2300|2297|2296|2298|2295" 
    Depth="0" 
    IncludePages="true" 
    Name="AreasofInquiry" 
    label="Areas of Inquiry">
```

And here is the full block of XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="RequirementsTabComponent">
    <xsl:if test="TaxonomyNavigation[@Name='AreasofInquiry']//Category">
      <p>
        <a href="{Page[@Name='AreasofInquiryLink']/@URL}"><strong>Areas of Inquiry Courses</strong></a>:&#160;
      </p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="AreasofInquiry" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I will appreciate any assistance you may have about how I might do this.

Comment: What bit of the XML generated by the CMS holds "whatever link name the user types into the CMS"? Is it the "label" attribute in this case?

Comment: Please show a complete XSLT stylesheet, and an input XML with all relevant elements (for example, where is `RequirementsTabComponent` or `Category`)?

Comment: Friendly, but important tip: please remember to indent your code (did it for you this time) when you post at any forum, it helps people help you by posting readable code.

Comment: Hi Tim Yes, it's the label attribute. Sorry for not mentioning. And thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, Sorry Abel...I did indent 4 spaces...and it looked right to me. Not sure what I did. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hi Mathias. My stylesheet is GIGANTIC, so I'm going to hold off for the moment. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the `label` attribute on the `TaxonomyNavigation` you need, then the expression you are looking for is this

```
<xsl:value-of select="TaxonomyNavigation[@Name='AreasofInquiry']/@Label" />
```

To put it in context, this is what your xslt template would look like:

```
<xsl:template match="RequirementsTabComponent">
    <xsl:if test="TaxonomyNavigation[@Name='AreasofInquiry']//Category">
      <p>
        <a href="{Page[@Name='AreasofInquiryLink']/@URL}">
            <strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="TaxonomyNavigation[@Name='AreasofInquiry']/@Label" /> 
            </strong>
        </a>
      </p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="AreasofInquiry" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```